# How to delete a transient on post/page publish?

Tags: query, transient

I have a transient set for a custom query. It expires in 30 days. But I also need it to expire once a new post/page is published. So that the new published post/page is available in that custom query. How to delete a transient on post/page publish?

How I set the transient:

```
// Get any existing copy of our transient data
   if ( false === ( $query = get_transient('d_results') ) ) {
    // It wasn't there, so regenerate the data and save the transient
    $randargs = array("post_type"=>"", "orderby"=>"", "order"=>"", "posts_per_page"=>-1);
    $query = new WP_Query($randargs);
    set_transient( 'd_results', $query, DAY_IN_SECONDS * 30);
   }
```

Comment: can u also add the codes which contain how u r setting the transient?

Comment: Updated the post with how the code of how I set the transient. I removed the argument's values from the query, but besides that everything is the same.

Comment: can you add some details on why would you do this, I mean why are u adding this transient at the first place?

Comment: The query returns over 600 posts. These posts are rarely updated, but everynow and then there's a new post before the 30 day expiration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am considering it for publication of a new post.

Add the below code in your active theme's **functions.php** file.

```
function wpse_delete_query_transient( $post ) {
    // Deletes the transient when a new post is published
    delete_transient( 'd_results' );
}
add_action( 'new_to_publish', 'wpse_delete_query_transient' );
```

This will delete the transient every time a new post is published.

if you want to delete the transients on differrent post status transitions, you may like to look into the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions)

Comment: Thanks @Maruti Mohanty. I was wondering based on your questions and my answers, if this is not a good solution for my problem? Would you not use transients?

Comment: I guess you have used transient very smartly and efficiently. I asked the questions to know why were u adding a query result to a transient but now i get your point :)

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware of Posts Status Transitions. I will be doing some good reading.