# How to rank custom post type from score points

Tags: custom-post-types, sort, rating

I use a custom field with is `casino_rank_score`with stores a point rating for example `4.9`

All casinos is stored on custom post type casinos.

I need to figure out how to get a rank listing like `RANKED #2 of 350 CASINOS` from `points`.

Wordpress stores this data to `wp_postmeta` table.

I can get all points from custom post type, from all casinos and put into array, but what i need to do next with custom php to make rank sorting.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22558371/get-ranking-of-query-when-getting-a-single-entry) but there is different structures and data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a `WP_Query` to get all the posts from post_type `casinos` and sort them with the custom field value `casino_rank_score`. Then you can further process it to display ranks.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'casinos',
    'meta_key' => 'casino_rank_score',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'posts_per_page' => 350,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
);

$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

If you only need to display one post only like `RANKED #2 of 350 CASINOS` then you can limit your results with `'posts_per_page' => 1,` and offset by 1 `'offset' => 1,`
This wway you will get 2nd ranked casino.

**EDIT**

To get rank you will need to run a custom query. And this is how you can get rank of current post in your custom query. It is optimized because we are only returning ID, no post data is requested so it's pretty fast. But to optimize it even further, you can cache this query with [Transients_API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) for couple of hours or days.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'casinos',
    'meta_key' => 'casino_rank_score',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'fields' => 'ids',
);

$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

global $post;

$total_casinos = $my_query->post_count;
$casinos_rank = array_search( $post->ID, $my_query->posts ) + 1;

echo "RANKED #" . $casinos_rank . " of " . $total_casinos . " CASINOS";
```

This is `tested` and `working`

Comment: But how i get the text ranked `#2` that will be getting dynamicaly from scrores data.

Comment: You can use a variable to count items and output counter value. Ok first tell me you knly want to return 1 item or list of items.

Comment: I need this data to show only on single casino template not make a rank listing.

Comment: Oh, that complicates the issue. Although we can always run a custom query on single page to get rank of the post but I will see it there is a simpler solution. Interesting question.

Comment: Yes. Interesting question. Also need looking that query and all staff is not so slow to make rank queries. Maybe this staff need make with php functions, get all data into array and then make a manupilations for that, not make a WP_Query?

Comment: Check edit in answer. There is no other way. You will have to run custom query but you can use `transient cache` to cache your custom query for a day or more (based on your requirements).

Comment: Ok. Tnx for help. I look on your code, and looking for similar solution. Yes, transient cahce is good for this, becouse ranking is not changing every hour or a day. Is there a way to rebuild a cache with transient (not plugins) when new custom post type like casino is published?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. You can fire `delete_transient` on post/page publish. Example here.  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/144411/how-to-delete-a-transient-on-post-page-publish